# TTL document in Mongo DB

Tags: database, mongodb, ttl

How do I add TTL (Time to Live) to a specific document in Mongo DB (Mongo database)? 
I made a document (tabke called task) and I want to make an expiry date such that when this date comes, the task is automatically deleted.

Thank you in advacnce

Comment: Did you read the documentation…? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time

Answer (score 5):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/), you need a `ttl` index

> For example, the following operation creates an index on the
>   log_events collection’s createdAt field and specifies the
>   expireAfterSeconds value of 3600 to set the expiration time to be one
>   hour after the time specified by createdAt.

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

> When adding documents to the log_events collection, set the createdAt
>   field to the current time:

```
db.log_events.insert( {
    "createdAt": new Date(), 
    "logEvent": 2, 
    "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

Comment: Can I contact you directly?

Comment: If the answer satisfies your question, please accept it. For further questions, please post a new question.