# How can I write a temporary file in node.js using a native approach?

Tags: node.js, file

Currently I'm facing a problem that requires me to write a file that has a expiration date, in other words, that destroy itself after some given time. There is a way to do this without any third party library?

I tried using `fs` module and creating a [temporary dir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsmkdtempprefix-options-callback) and inserting a permanent file that in the future will be destroyed with the temporary dir... But this is not the right solution, I need specifically a temporary file!

Comment: As best I know, there is no such thing as an expiring file.  I don't know of any Mac/Linux/Windows OS that supports that feature.  So, there would have to be some agent that keeps track of expiration dates and regularly does cleanup and removes expired files.   If you already have a nodejs server running 24x7, then it would be easy to implement such an agent in your server with a simple timer that wakes up every so often and calls a cleanup function.

Comment: If you were clever and allowed to mess with the filename of these temporary expiring files, you could even encode the expiration date/time in the filename so a simple scan of a known directory could identify which files are ready for desctruction.

Comment: Some similar discussion here: https://serverfault.com/questions/598133/expire-files-in-a-folder-delete-files-after-x-days

Comment: I haven't figured out about temporary files, I think they just don't exist yet. Maybe in the end I'll create an observer for the temp files. Also, the expiration date in the filename is a nice touch, I'll do something similar using the file's metadata if the format allows me to create custom metadata. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most OS file systems don't offer a TTL mechanism. Using a storage abstraction (database) which supports that mechanism is a better idea than trying to use the file system paradigm. Jumpstart your research: [Which major database platforms support TTL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/100807/173249), [TTL document in Mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48426504/438273)

Answer (score -1):

Here's some code that gets temporary filenames with an encoded expiration date in them and offers a function for cleaning up any expired temporary files.  The caller can call `getExpiringTempFilename("myprefix", "tmp", 1000 * 60 * 60)` to get a unique expiring filename (full path) that would expire in an hour and then it's up to the caller to actually write to it and create it.  The caller can then call `removeExpiredFiles("myprefix")` upon whatever time interval the caller wants.  For example, you could clean these up every hour with something like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
    removeExpiredFiles("myprefix");
}, 1000 * 60 * 60);
```

And, here's the code:

```
import os from 'node:os';
import path from 'node:path';
import fs from 'node:fs';
const fsp = fs.promises;

const expireDir = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "expiring");

try {
    fs.mkdirSync(expireDir)
} catch (e) {
    if (e.code !== "EEXIST") {
        // only process the error if it's not because the directory aleady exists
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
}

function makeNonce() {
    const rand = Math.random().toString().replace(".", "").replace(/^0+/, "");
    const now = Date.now().toString();
    const nonce = `${rand}_${now}`;
    return nonce;
}

export function getExpiringTempFilename(base, ext, tFromNow) {
    const expireT = Date.now() + tFromNow;
    const expireDate = new Date(expireT);
    const expireStr = expireDate.toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-");
    return path.join(expireDir, `${base}_${expireStr}_${makeNonce()}${ext ? "." + ext : ""}`);
}

// use this regex to test if file is EXACTLY the full date format
// because new Date() is far too permissive
const dateRegex = /\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z/;

// this must be called with the same base argument that getExpiringTempFilename was called with
export async function removeExpiredFiles(base) {
    const files = (await fsp.readdir(expireDir)).filter((name) => {
        return name.startsWith(base + "_");
    });
    const now = Date.now();
    for (let f of files) {
        // remove base from start of string
        // we do it this way rather than rely on the .split() in case base contains an underscore
        try {
            let str = f.slice(base.length + 1);
            let pieces = str.split("_");
            let dateStr = pieces[0];
            // put the colons back in the time
            if (pieces.length !== 3) {
                // skip files that aren't the exact right format
                continue;
            }
            const datePieces = dateStr.split("T");
            datePieces[1] = datePieces[1].replace(/-/g, ":");
            dateStr = datePieces.join("T");
            if (!dateRegex.test(dateStr)) {
                // skip files that aren't the exact right format
                continue;
            }
            let date = new Date(dateStr);
            if (date < now) {
                try {
                    let fullname = path.join(expireDir, f);
                    await fsp.unlink(fullname);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(`invalid date format, ${f}`);
        }
    }
}
```

This code attempts to be very cautious and only remove filenames that have the right prefix, match the precise format of the filename, have the exact right date format and have a date that has expired.

It creates files with a name like this:

```
"base_2023-03-13T02-15-33.418Z_1935457260903528_1678673732418.tmp"
```

where the "base" and "tmp" parts are arguments you pass in.  The `2023-03-13T02-15-33.418Z` is the expiration date.  `1935457260903528` is a randomly generated value.  `1678673732418` is a timestamp which further guards against duplicate filenames.

The base part of the name is meant to distinguish expiring temp files from any other files that happen to be in the same directory, though the code also requires exact format match for other parts of the name too.

Comment: Beware: `TMPDIR` is not guaranteed to resolve to the same directory (especially across reboots). The resolution of `TMPDIR` is controlled by the OS — as is the eviction policy of its contents — and these are typically not configurable by the user.

Comment: @jsejcksn - If the OP wants these files to last longer than the usual duration of a temp file, they can supply their own directory to put them in.